# Random forest and bagging: if both generate deep, non-pruned trees then what's the difference?

Tags: random-forest, cart, bagging

I understand that random forest only considers a subset of predictors at each node, but if you are generating deep trees then you'll eventually include all predictors in your model, the only difference being the order that they appear: that with bagging the strong and highly correlated predictors will occupy higher nodes, whereas in random forests the stronger and highly correlated predictors will be more evenly distributed throughout the tree, right? I just don't understand what difference it makes which nodes the predictors occupy if trees generated using either bagging or random forests contain all combinations of predictors anyways.